# Kendo UI MobileButton URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a MVC .NET site with the next Pages:

Home/Index
Home/Update

When I access to Home/Update in Mobile view, in the menubar, we have a kendo MobileNavBar with a Buttom to go at Home/Index again, this is the code.

```
@(Html.Kendo().MobileNavBar()
    .Content(navbar =>
        @<text>
            @navbar.ViewTitle("")
            @(Html.Kendo().MobileButton()
                .Align(MobileButtonAlign.Left)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "nav-button" })
                .Url(@Url.Action("Index","Home"), "Home")
                .Text("HOME")
            )
```

The problem is that, when I cliked on Home buttom in Mobile View, this redirect to xxxx/Home/Update#/**Home** and this is not correct. I would like to redirect to xxxx/Home/Index

**What is the correct way to do this?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MobileNavBar()
    .Content(navbar =>
        @<text>
            @navbar.ViewTitle("")
            @(Html.Kendo().MobileButton()
                .Align(MobileButtonAlign.Left)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "nav-button" })
                .Url(@Url.Action("Index","Home"))
                .Text("HOME")
            )
```